# How to add days in <input type="date">

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have this sets of inputs here;

```
Days:<select id="select">
         <option value="150 days">150 days</option>
         <option value="200 days">200 days</option>
       </select>
Date1:<input type="date" id="date1">
Date2:<input type="date" id="date2">
```

I dont know how to properly explain this, but what's supposed to happen is this:

if user selects 150 days, it will be added to date1 (which is also inputted by the user) and will be automatically shown in date2.

note that date1 is not the current date...

Comment: Explain more about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the value of `date1`, transform it into a date, add to it the days from your select element and put it into the `date2` field. You can do that in JavaScript creating a function that triggers on change of the `date1` field.

HTML:

```
Days:<select id="select">
         <option value="150">150 days</option>
         <option value="200">200 days</option>
       </select>
Date1:<input type="date" onchange="setSecondDate();" id="date1">
Date2:<input type="date" id="date2">
```

JavaScript:

```
function setSecondDate() {
    var days = document.getElementById("select").value;
    var date = new Date(document.getElementById("date1").value);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(days));
    document.getElementById("date2").valueAsDate = date;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/vk1ujuu2/

---Edit---

If you need it to work in all browsers you can use jQuery UI's datepicker.
You just need to include jQuery and jQuery UI and write an additional function for parsing the date to string.

Includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Parsing function:

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
  var mm = this.getMonth() + 1;
  var dd = this.getDate();

  return [this.getFullYear(),
          (mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
          (dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd
         ].join('-');
};
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vk1ujuu2/5/

Comment: You might need to also cover cases where the browser doesn't support input type date or *valueAsDate*.